# The `font-inter` class does not exist

Tags: tailwind-css, web-development-server, next.js13

```
The `font-inter` class does not exist. If `font-inter` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.I am getting this error in my nextjs app.
```

I am expercting to resolve this font-error in tail wind css.
The error is occuring in global.css file in which the nextapp is not able to resolve some tailwind css classes.At first I thought the error is in [This image is the screen shot of the error occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32be4.png)

```
    .app {
  @apply relative z-10 flex justify-center items-center flex-col max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-16 px-6;
}

.black_btn {
  @apply rounded-full border border-black bg-black py-1.5 px-5 text-white transition-all hover:bg-white hover:text-black text-center text-sm font-inter flex items-center justify-center;
}

.outline_btn {
  @apply rounded-full border border-black bg-transparent py-1.5 px-5 text-black transition-all hover:bg-black hover:text-white text-center text-sm font-inter flex items-center justify-center;
}

.head_text {
  @apply mt-5 text-5xl font-extrabold leading-[1.15] text-black sm:text-6xl;
}

.orange_gradient {
  @apply bg-gradient-to-r from-amber-500 via-orange-600 to-yellow-500 bg-clip-text text-transparent;
}

.green_gradient {
  @apply bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-green-500 bg-clip-text text-transparent;
}

.blue_gradient {
  @apply bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-600 to-cyan-600 bg-clip-text text-transparent;
}

.desc {
  @apply mt-5 text-lg text-gray-600 sm:text-xl max-w-2xl;
}
```

Comment: What code generates this error?

Comment: the global.css file code is having error

Comment: And have you defined `font-inter` in there somewhere? Because it's not built into Tailwind.

Comment: ya made font-inter in global.css

Comment: Could you show us that CSS?

Comment: I have added the code sample in question description.

Comment: The `font-inter` class is not defined anywhere in that code sample. It is **used**, but it is never **defined**.

Answer (score 4):

It's seem like you have been watching from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wm5gMKuwSYk right?

He given a `tailwind.config.js` for you to replace your own `tailwind.config.js` [[link]](https://gist.github.com/adrianhajdin/6df61c6cd5ed052dce814a765bff9032). (At `fontFamily` by adding custom font name was called `inter`, then `font-inter` will be able to use in your `global.css`)

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        satoshi: ['Satoshi', 'sans-serif'],
        inter: ['Inter', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      colors: {
        'primary-orange': '#FF5722',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

After that, "The `font-inter` class does not exist." should be solved.